# How do I downgrade my Google Drive storage account?

Tags: google-drive

I have a Google Drive account and I want to downgrade from the 200gb plan to the 100gb plan.  If I navigate to https://one.google.com/about/plans my only option is to upgrade.

[image]

Opening a https://one.google.com/about/plans on a private browser shows me the basic and free google drive plans do still exist.
[image]

How do I downgrade my account?

*I am using only 91gb of storage.*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Got it, I needed to go to

https://one.google.com/settings

*(are google purposefully making it easy for me to spend more money but difficult to spend less money?)*

Comment: This does not currently work for me. It doesn't show downgrade options. I'm currently on a 2TB free trial; maybe that matters?

Comment: Dark patterns 101

Answer (score 2):

I'll add to the above answer as it's been moved again and they only allow upgrades in the storage setting.

https://one.google.com/settings

Go to: **Settings** > **Change Membership Plan**

You can downgrade in there.

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't for your exact situation but I hope this helps others since Google seems to keep changing the exact steps. This was the first post I found which helped me get to the correct answer.

Their verbiage for downgrading your storage involves cancelling your membership. Yes, you want to do this in order to back onto the free 15GB tier.

They don't want you cancelling so easily. After cancelling, they won't pro-rate a refund. You will be downgraded right before the next billing cycle.

Go to https://one.google.com/settings

1. Cancel membership
   [image]
2. Yes, cancel membership for real
   [image]

Which leads you to https://play.google.com/store/account/subscriptions

1. Manage
   [image]
2. Cancel subscription
   [image]
3. Give a reason
   [image]
4. Yes, cancel subscription
   [image]